# Slow test cases when using elastic search (pyes)

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pyes

I recently added elastic search to our stack and it is slowing down our test cases.

In order to keep the tests from trampling each other I isolated them by index.
This seems to be the cause. Creating and Deleting indexes seems to be slow.

I haven't been able to find an equivalent to "truncate", but I thought I would ask.

Also, a few years ago when I was using ES with Java I used an in memory node for the tests and that was very fast. I don't think pyes has this option.

Comment: Can you confirm the requirements for your tests? It sounds like you're running parallel unit tests on the full stack - would that be correct? Do you *have* to have ES up for the tests - could you mock out pyes?

Comment: I'm not running parallel. I decided to use a shared index for the tests and then do a deleteByQuery. That is *much* faster than deleting the entire index and recreating